# External USB drive on xen windows guest

Tags: windows, xen, hard-drive, xenserver

I have an external USB 2Tb drive I'm trying to use with a xen guest.
Xen Center 6.1 sees the drive in the removable storage repository and I can assign it to a guest.

But the guest (tested Server-2012 and Windws7-x64) see it as an uninitialized disk in disk manager, with a size  >14500 Gb (!) and give an I/O error when I try and initialize it either as MBR or GPT.

The drive tested and formatted perfectly when plugged into a regular machine.

Comment: are you trying to use it as a mass storage device for the VM itself or as a xenserver local storage repository?

Comment: It  is recognised in the removable SR of the host, I assign it to the guest as a local storage in the guest.

Comment: have you tried creating an sr and trying out with it?  
xe sr-create name-label="external drive" content-type=user type=lvm device-config:device=/dev/sdx1